# ROR: hidden form for values arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a typical ruby hash called `schema`:

```
{ 
  "car"=>{"col"=>["blue","red"], "engine"=>["HHd4M","Rafa"]},
  "train"=>{"col"=>"black","green"], "engine"=>["8495f","mad"]}
}
```

I want to create a hidden form for this hash.

```
<%=form_tag send_form_database_querys_path, method: :get do %>
    <% schema.each do |vehicle,opt| 
            opt.each do |key,vals| #key = col or key = engine, vals = array
                vals.each do |val| #val = each element in an array
            %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag "schema[#{vehicle}][#{key}][]", val  %>
    <% end end end %>

        <%= button_tag :class => "btn btn-warning", :name => 'delete' do %> <%= t "arraydb_delete_selected" %> <% end %>    
    <% end %>
```

Somehow if I submit it, it tells me "Bad request"
What is a problem with my hidden form?

Comment: please add some more code

Comment: What tells you "Bad request"?  Can you add the relevant part of your log file to your question please, with the stack trace and the contents of params.

Comment: The only thing regarding this error in the log file is the following line: !! Invalid request
!! Invalid request, nothing more

Comment: Give us a request example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change form method to `post`.

```
<%=form_tag send_form_database_querys_path, method: :post do %>
```

Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `[` in your hash after `"train"=>{"col"=>`. It should be

```
{ 
  "car"=>{"col"=>["blue","red"], "engine"=>["HHd4M","Rafa"]},
  "train"=>{"col"=>["black","green"], "engine"=>["8495f","mad"]}
}
```